# Android market app Link

Tags: android, google-play

I want to write an app which launches android market.
(The activity should only one activity)
so plz refer me the android market link or any suggestion.

Comment: Can you please re-word your question. It is really difficult to understand grammatically. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"The activity should only one activity"*?

Comment: Alexandre Jasmin ,  prolink007 :

I want to do a android market application. so how to do the app. plz suggest me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=barcodes");
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
startActivity(intent);
```

This example code will launch the market and search for barcodes.

Comment: The question specifically asks for the Android Market to be launched, whereas this Intent will launch ANY market app. I would expect the answer to include something along the lines of the "com.android.vending" package. Unfortunately, any activity name (in the Android Market app) may well change from one release to another, so I don't know of any good solution to this.

Comment: This Intent tells Android to resolve the intent to something that can handle the market request. If there are more than one market installed the user will be prompted to choice one. Hard coding the target to something specific isn't the best idea given all the variety of android devices.

Comment: Hard-coding "com.android.vending" is the only way to detect the presence of and then launch the Android Market app. Sometimes you absolutely do not want the user to be able to select which market app to launch. For example, Amazon AppStore insists that you do not use market:// intent uris because they may end up taking the user to a competing app store.

Answer (score 0):

To send an SMS with a link to an app on the market place, the simple approach is to use bit.ly for a URL Shortener.

When the browser on the phone resolved the URL it will prompt if they want to open it up in the market place.  This approach while not perfect works for my apps